# tableViewConctroller Stopped Recognize methods [MAJOR ERROR]

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, unrecognized-selector

Ok, this is the weirdest thing Xcode gave me ever. I have a Table View Controller named "friendsTVCTableViewController". It was working fine today. I didn't changed ANY code of this class today. NOTHING. When I was testing another class (Because this other class was giving me some weird errors too -NSMUtableArrays wasn't adding objects), I started all of a sudden receiving errors from this friends tabel view.  These errors are saying that none of the method (selectors) on the class exists! This problem is weird because on the app, this friends table view is always loded and tested. Why on earth did it stopped working now??

Here's a piece of the code:

```
#import "friendsTVCTableViewController.h"
#import "currentUser.h"
#import "friend.h"
#import "Imager.h"
#import "configurations.h"
#import "JSONDictionaryExtensions.h"
#import "CustomInP.h"

@interface friendsTVCTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation friendsTVCTableViewController{
    NSMutableArray *tmpArrayOfFriends;
    NSMutableArray *friendRequested;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    currentUser *thisUser;
    configurations *saver;
    bool flagIsAdding;
    UITextField *addFriendField;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingAddFriend;
    NSMutableArray *mimosDownloading;
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSMutableArray *imagers;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imagers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [imagers removeAllObjects];

    tmpArrayOfFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    flagIsAdding = NO;
    thisUser = [currentUser instance];
    saver = [[configurations alloc]init];
    mimosDownloading = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    currentUser *tmpUser = [[currentUser alloc]init];
    friendRequested =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getFriendsRequested) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; //UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(checkRequests) toTarget:self withObject:nil];//UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
    tmpUser = [saver loadCustomObject];
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
        if(([tmpUser.userID isEqualToString:thisUser.userID]) && (tmpUser.friendsList != nil)){
            thisUser.friendsList = tmpUser.friendsList;
            NSLog(@"[FRIENDS VC]:DISPATCH ONCE LOADED RIENDS.");
        }
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadFriendsList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];//UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadGroupList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];//UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
    });

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar@2x.png"]];;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28.0f]}];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    imagers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //[thisUser organizeFriendsList];


    //[self loadFriendsList];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(mimoDownloaderChecker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; //UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
}
```

ALL of the selectors with error above, are declared inside the class and were working fine!
Even when I try to call ANY method by [self methodName] i get the error "no visible @interface for 'friendsTVCTableViewController' declares the selector 'methodName'".

Does any one have a clue of what I could do?
I already tryed to Delete the class and add it again
Clear the project
Punch the MacBook (poor boy)

I really have no idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your variables within the @interface

```
@interface friendsTVCTableViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *tmpArrayOfFriends;
    NSMutableArray *friendRequested;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    currentUser *thisUser;
    configurations *saver;
    bool flagIsAdding;
    UITextField *addFriendField;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingAddFriend;
    NSMutableArray *mimosDownloading;
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSMutableArray *imagers;
}

@end

@implementation friendsTVCTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imagers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [imagers removeAllObjects];

    tmpArrayOfFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    flagIsAdding = NO;
    thisUser = [currentUser instance];
    saver = [[configurations alloc]init];
    mimosDownloading = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    currentUser *tmpUser = [[currentUser alloc]init];
    friendRequested =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getFriendsRequested) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; //UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(checkRequests) toTarget:self withObject:nil];//UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
    tmpUser = [saver loadCustomObject];
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
        if(([tmpUser.userID isEqualToString:thisUser.userID]) && (tmpUser.friendsList != nil)){
            thisUser.friendsList = tmpUser.friendsList;
            NSLog(@"[FRIENDS VC]:DISPATCH ONCE LOADED RIENDS.");
        }
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadFriendsList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];//UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadGroupList) toTarget:self withObject:nil];//UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
    });

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar@2x.png"]];;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28.0f]}];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    imagers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //[thisUser organizeFriendsList];


    //[self loadFriendsList];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(mimoDownloaderChecker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; //UNDECLARED SELECTOR ERROR
}

// Rest of code

@end
```